# Account reputation different on other SE sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation display bug… Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again)

On Stack Overflow, I have 85 rep, and and when I go to profile and check account I also have 85. However, if I check any other SE site (including this meta) it says 90. I imagine this is a change of vote issue, but I'm just curious how I can 'refresh' my profile such that it will be updated.

Comment: Caching.  The answer is always caching.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess what I'm curious to know is how long it takes to update then if there's nothing I can do to speed it up.

Comment: I feel like this has been asked before....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will update in time. The accounts for other sites are all cached.

Comment: How often does it update? It's been like this for close to 24+ hours.